# How can I change the installation directory in Orange Pi from internal storage to external storage running

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I am running android Operating Software in Orange Pi. How can I change the installation directory from internal storage to external storage (SD Card). As my application file size is 1gb ++, the internal storage of Orange Pi is only left with 1gb. So, the storage is not enough. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Experts can clarify better but when the OS boots, it looks for files in the internal storage, does it's checks and at a much later stage the ext.SD comes into play. Ext.SD is only meant for storage of media, not designed to boot OS (unlike PCs where you can boot into the OS available on flash USB drive)//You can read more in the [answers here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Android+boot+process)